# How do I target TFS build agents that does not have a specific tag?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

Our MS build setup has several build machines with multiple agents. The agents are tagged with different software installed on the build machines. My build is looking for two tags using "MatchAtLeast". Recently, TFS has occasionally picked another build machine, on which it always fails. I believe it might be because of a certain other software package that is installed on that particular machine, and so I would like to *exclude* any machine from the ones available for my build that has a specific tag representing the offending software.

I guess I could add tags to everything that does not have that software, but that seems silly, and then if that ever do get installed, the person adding it would need to not just add a tag for the newly installed software, but also remove this other tag stating that it doesn't have that software.

So is there a way to configure your build definition to ***avoid*** build agents with a certain tag?

We are using TFS 2012 update 2.

Answer (score 2):

In the advanced tab of the build definition, you can define agent names as well as tags. By default it's set to * but you can use the name of the agent(s) you want to target

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is what the build machine admin suggested as well, but this would limit the available build agents to only the ones on a particular machine. Let's say you want all agents on machines Build6 and Build7, but not any on machine Build4. Can you do a separated list? reading the limited documentation, it sounds like you can only do wildcard characters * and ? and that's not expressive enough for my scenario, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: No you can only select a single server. On our farm we have a set of identical agents (16 or so) We don't allow any software to be installed other then thigs requried to run a build i.e. the build service and Visual Studio. For Binary dependancies (e.g. 3rd party libraries) we check them in to TFS and bring them down to the build servers as part of the build (by adding them to the workspace) this way we can be sure that all builds will work on all agents.